# Probability of multiple trials?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

give an event $E$ and probability that event occurs as P. If it was attempted $1000$ times. What would be the answers to the following question.

- probability of at least the event occurring one time ? is it $1-(1-P)^{1000}$
- probability of at most the event occurring one time? is it $P*(1-P)^{999}$
- probability of at least the event occurring three times? is it $P^3*(1-(1-P)^{997})$
- probability of at most the event occurring three times ? is it $P^3*(1-P)^{997}$
- probability of event occurring more than one time ? is it  $P^2*(1-(1-P)^{998})$
- probability of event not occurring at all ? is it $(1-p)^{1000}$

Comment: "$-3$ down vote favorite"....did you cut and paste this from another question on this site?

Comment: What have you tried?  These are all basic questions in the use of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: @lulu. Yea it was 1st posted at mathoverflow. And as for your question i have just started to learn Probability.So these are some of the questions that has popped in to my mind

Comment: Well, read that link on the binomial distribution.  You can simple expressions which exactly answer these questions.  Also, you can read about approximate methods which are useful when the numbers involved get larger.

Comment: "(is it 1000P)" Well, let's see. If your experiment is flipping a coin, and $E$ is "get heads", then $P$ is $0.5$. On the other hand $1000P = 500$. Can a probability ever be $500$?

Comment: Can I ask a dumb question what is occuring “ones?” Is it one time?

Comment: @kimiTanaka yea what i meant to say was "one time"

Comment: @lulu i have added possible answers could you comment. thanks

Comment: @Arthur. you are right. Stupid me i have changed the answer

Comment: Well, the second one is wrong.  Let $P_i$ be the probability that it occurs exactly $i$ times, so you want $P_0+P_1$.  As you point out $P_0=(1-p)^{1000}$.   From the binomial distribution we get  $P_1=1000\times p\times (1-p)^{999}$.

Comment: @lulu I am bit confused are you saying that only the 2nd one is wrong? I used the same logic for the 4th question. taking your answer in to consideration, shouldn't the 4th question's answer be 166167000*(P^3)*(1-P)^997) + (499500*(P^2)*(1-P)^998) + (1000*(P)*(1-P)^999)

Comment: No, I wasn't saying that.  Others are wrong along the same lines.  For the third, say, we have $P_3=\binom {1000}3\times p^3\times (1-p)^{997}$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

The probability it happens $k$ times in $n$ independent attempts is $P(k)={n \choose k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$. Your attempts seem to have ignored the binomial co-efficients which count the different possible orderings of successes.

To answer the questions, consider:

- $1$ minus probability $k=0$
- probability $k=0$ or $k=1$
- probability $k=0$ or $k=1$ or $k=2$ or $k=3$
- $1$ minus probability $k=0$ or $k=1$ or $k=2$
- $1$ minus probability $k=0$ or $k=1$
- probability $k=0$

Answer (score 0):

- probability of at least the event occurring one time ? is it $1-(1-P)^{1000}$

You don't have any other way to count the event not occurring in any other way.

The  result is $\binom{1000}{1000}$$\times${$1-(1-P)^{1000}$}

- probability of at most the event occurring one time? is it $P*(1-P)^{999}$

As in Lulu's comment, it has been already explained, you need to consider not occuring and only once the event occurs. Only once the event occurs, you have many other ways to count them such as the way at 1st observaton the event happens and the rest of observations the event not happens or the way at 2nd observations the event does not happen and so on so forth.

The  result is altogether not occuring and occring once.

$\binom{1000}{1000}$$\times${$1-(1-P)^{1000}$} +  $\binom{1000}{1}$$\times${$p\times(1-P)^{999}$}

- probability of at least the event occurring three times? is it $P^3*(1-(1-P)^{997})$

Now You need to add another scenario the event happens twice to the last one. And you have the probability of at most twice happens. You need to remove them from all the event 1. Now you get the probability of at least three times happens.

$1$ - {$\binom{1000}{1000}$$\times${$1-(1-P)^{1000}$} +  $\binom{1000}{1}$$\times${$p\times(1-P)^{999}$} +  $\binom{1000}{2}$$\times$${p^{2}\times(1-P)^{998}}$}

- probability of at most the event occurring three times ? is it $P^3*(1-P)^{997}$

You need to add the probaility of three times happen to the probaility of at most twice happen.

$\binom{1000}{1000}$$\times${$1-(1-P)^{1000}$} +  $\binom{1000}{1}$$\times${$p\times(1-P)^{999}$} +  $\binom{1000}{2}$$\times$${p^{2}\times(1-P)^{998}}$ +  $\binom{1000}{3}$$\times$${p^{3}\times(1-P)^{997}}$

- probability of event occurring more than one time ? is it  $P^2*(1-(1-P)^{998})$

$1$ - { the probaility of at most the event occuring one time}

- the probability of event not occurring at all ? is it $(1-p)^{1000}$

Yes.